# How to correctly write an array of chars to a text file

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file-writing

At first, I would like to point out that despite using C ++ I cannot use strings or vectors. It is like C with objects.

Ok I have class A with char* test() method:

```
char* A::test()
{
    char to_return[3*this->some_value+3];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->some_value; i++)
    {
        to_return[3*i] = '♥';
        to_return[3*i+1] = 'b';
        to_return[3*i+2] = ' ';
    }
    char* dto_return = to_return;
    return std::move(dto_return);
}
```

next in object of class B I have:

```
ofstream file;
file.open("myfile.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);
file.close();
file.open("myfile.txt");
char* to_write = a_obj->test();
size_t len = strlen(to_write);
file.write((char*)&len, sizeof(len));
file.write(to_write, len);
file.close();
```

(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991417/writing-char-to-binary-file-using-ostreamwrite))

but the content of the file is:

```
       ¥b ¥b ¥b m
```

and it is definitely not what I'm looking for. The content should be:

```
♥b ♥b ♥b
```

How to fix that?

Comment: `'♥'` has implementation-defined value if `♥` cannot be represented by one byte in your character code.

Comment: Either make `to_return` static and always return a `char*` pointer on the same buffer, or allocate a new buffer with new/malloc each time you call A::test() and cleanup (delete/free) later. Right now the content of `to_return` is deallocated at the end the function, so pointing to it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MikeCAT maybe not (although it is displaying in console). How to fix that
m88 the same: how to fix that.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz I literally give you 2 ways to fix that in the 1st half of my comment.

Comment: @m88 Ok, I undrestood your hint after MikeCat full answer.

Comment: Be aware that the size printed in advance might result in some additional characters getting visible if its bytes are in range of printable characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are:

- `to_return` is a local array that ends its lifetime on returning from the function, so returning its pointer is a bad idea.
- `'♥'` may differ from what you want, especially when `♥` cannot be represented by one byte in your character code.

To overcome this problems:

- Allocate a dynamic array that persists after returning from the function.
- Use string literal to represent the characters to add.

```
char* A::test()
{
    const char *part = "♥b ";
    size_t part_len = strlen(part);
    char *to_return = new char[part_len*this->some_value+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->some_value; i++)
    {
        strcpy(to_return + part_len * i, part);
    }
    return to_return;
}
```

The dynamic array returned should be freed via `delete[]` after completed to use.

```
char* to_write = a_obj->test();

// ...

delete[] to_write;
```

Comment: Did you forget about to_Return in `strcpy`? Now it gives an error `invalid conversion from const char* to char*`

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Ok. There was one more bug in my code - I shouldn't write this `file.write((char*)&len, sizeof(len));`. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: I have one more question. Because heart-sign is from another function which is `char getHeart() conts {return heart;}` and heart is: `char heart = 3` (where 3 is a number). I tried `const char *part = new char(getHeart());` but it is not my sign.

Comment: C-style strings (to be dealts with C library like `strcpy()` and `strlen()`) have to be terminated by `'\0'`. The array should be `const char* part = new char[2]{getHeart(), '\0'};`

Comment: I have only `[][][]` in my file (or other strange symbols if opened in Notepad++)